# Restoring from Postgres sql file

Tags: database, postgresql, pg-restore

I have a backup from PostgresSQL database created this way:

`/usr/bin/pg_dump --no-owner --no-acl > dump.sql`

When I try to restore on a different machine:

`psql db < dump.sql` it trows many errors: `invalid command \N`

When I try to use `pg_restore`:

`pg_restore dump.sql -d db`

Different error: `pg_restore: [archiver] input file appears to be a text format dump. Please use psql.`

According to [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/backup-dump.html) this should be a non issue.

Any way to tell `psql` that \N character is a null value?

Comment: try `psql -U role -d dbname -f filename.sql` remove `<`

Comment: @dwir182 same error with `invalid command \N`

Comment: You backup use `pg_dump` seems weird.. There are no db you backup or even role To specify schema in db?

Comment: Please show us the *first* error message you get.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Oh hi me, it's me

Make sure:

- Database exists
- Importing user has permissions
- Get the first error before `\N` ones flood in
- `psql -d database -f backup.sql -U user` should do the trick for importing

Also eat healthy and get good rest. k bye

Answer (score 2):

this may be the case if the columns in the table and the columns in the file not match